# Help in Understanding Variational Autoencoder Size of Latent Variables

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders

I'm trying to understand further how a variational autoencoder works beyond the conceptual level. However I'm still confused as to what the "vector of mean and variances" can look like and to digest it in a simplistic way.

For example, I understand that the latent variables in an autoencoder represents the compressed features of some input X and in the context of a variational autoencoder, you try to get the probabilistic distribution represented by mean and variance of the latent variable. So does this mean that:

a. If I have 5 latent variables in an autoencoder, in the context of a variational autoencoder, I should have 10 parameters (2 sets of mean and variances for each latent variables) represented as 2 vectors (1 vector of size 5 for means and 1 vector of size 5 for variances). In sampling/decoding, I can pass 5 means and 5 variances to generate an output.

OR

b. Based on code examples, the representation of mean and variances are always 2 values (during sampling, you can randomize just a single mean and variance).

Thanks in advance. My goal is to be able to simplify the explanation since most examples online always give just 2 variables for decoding (just a single mean and variance value).

Answer (score 5):

It's a). In VAE you assume that distribution over latent variables is **multivariate normal with diagonal covariance matrix**, and penalize using KL divergence from standard normal distribution. This KL divergence can be calculated using mean and covariance matrix of the distribution that is being sampled.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So when sampling, I just pass in values for latent variables (let's say 5 values) from (0, 1) right? The closer the value it is to 0 the less likely or farther the sample is from the distribution for that latent variable?

Comment: I don't know what 'pass in values for latent variables' means. And where does (0,1) come from

Comment: I mean when sampling from a trained autoencoder. So let's say I have an autoencoder with an architecture of 10 as my input vector and 5 as my latent space vector. (10 input x, 5 latent z and 10 output y). If I were to create a variational autoencoder, this means I would want to sample base off of the 5 latent variables right? So each of those latent variables would have some mean and variance. Does this mean that given the trained autoencoder, I would have to pass 5 values in the decoding process where each value is from (0, 1)? Hope it made sense.

Comment: I don't get where you get values from (0,1) from.

When you have an autoencoder it contains parameters for the distribution on latent variable that can be used for sampling.

Comment: The (0,1) values are for sampling with a trained variational autoencoder. Check the bottom part of this article (https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/12/10/variational-autoencoder/) for reference. Sorry I can't explain it as clearly.

Comment: I don't see (0,1) expression anywhere else than in N(0,1) which means normal distribution with mean 0 and std deviation 1.